# Elasticsearch missing aggs

Tags: elasticsearch

I am doing an Elasticsearch query and having problems with the aggs going missing.

If I do the query below I get the aggs back without issue:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*wet*",
          "fields": [
            "Name",
            "Summary",
            "Description",
            "Location",
            "Features",
            "TypeName",
            "CategoryName"
          ]
        },
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "TypeID": "13"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TypeID"
      }
    },
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CategoryID"
      }
    },
    "max_price": {
      "max": {
        "field": "Price"
      }
    },
    "min_price": {
      "min": {
        "field": "Price"
      }
    },
    "filter-type": {
      "term": {
        "TypeID": "13"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "_score": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "explain": false
}
```

However, as soon as I add a filter, the aggs are no longer returned. I can't see what I am doing wrong so any help would be really appreciated.

The one that doesn't return aggs looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*wet*",
          "fields": [
            "Name",
            "Summary",
            "Description",
            "Location",
            "Features",
            "TypeName",
            "CategoryName"
          ]
        },
        "filter": {
          "term": {
            "TypeID": "13"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "type": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "TypeID"
      }
    },
    "category": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "CategoryID"
      }
    },
    "max_price": {
      "max": {
        "field": "Price"
      }
    },
    "min_price": {
      "min": {
        "field": "Price"
      }
    },
    "filter-type": {
      "term": {
        "TypeID": "13"
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "_score": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  },
  "explain": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for [filters aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html). You have to wrap all you aggregation inside filter like this

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*wet*",
          "fields": [
            "Name",
            "Summary",
            "Description",
            "Location",
            "Features",
            "TypeName",
            "CategoryName"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "TypeID": "13"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "filter-type": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "TypeID": "13"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "type": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "TypeID"
          }
        },
        "category": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "CategoryID"
          }
        },
        "max_price": {
          "max": {
            "field": "Price"
          }
        },
        "min_price": {
          "min": {
            "field": "Price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also in this case `filter` in `aggs` is redundant as you are already using the same filter in your query.